# PyMed query top results from PubMed

Tags: pubmed, pubmed-api

Is there way to get the top results on PyMed for a specific query using results = pubmed.query(query, max_results=10)?
We seem to get a random 10, not the top 10, but would like the top 10. Is there another way to query, or a parameter we're missing?
Thanks!